# convert mdi application to mvvm wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, desktop-application, mdi

I have a winform application that I want to convert to WPF

It has a main form (MDI) and the children can call each other as well.

I read that MDI is not a good practice according to the mvvm. But I saw that application have the look and feel that I want (e.g:Prism- I was told that it is too complicated for beginners and for a small application like I need).

Do you know a small WPF project that follow the mvvm rules and has the look and feel of MDI application?

Thanks 
Asaf

Answer (score 4):

MDI is a GUI design pattern.  MVVM is a programming design pattern.  The two really aren't related at all.  You can do either one or both together.

It is true, however, that many GUI design experts frown upon MDI but that's entirely because of usability for the end-user... not because of the underlying code.

Perhaps if you describe or provide a mockup of the UI you want to create we can provide guidance on how to implement it in WPF.